# Using PayPal for a trial application

Tags: paypal, credit-card

Lets say customers have signed up for a free trial and should be charged only at the end of their trial period if they want to continue their service. I'm looking to do the following via PayPal's APIs:

- Before storing their CC data, check to see if the card is valid
- Create, Update, Delete, and Get credit card information on PayPal
- Also link a user's CC data to their username or ID on my system
- Store CC data but bill the customers later (needed for a trial application)

Are these doable on PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do some of the above features in PayPal.

Here is what you can do in PayPal.

***First option*** - DoReferenceTransactionReq (charge time and amount can be vary)

1) Charge customer's credit card ***first*** (let say $5)

2) Save that transaction id

3) Reference that transaction id for next billing (do not need credti card again)

***Second option*** - CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq (Recurrening time and amount are fixed)

1) Create recurrent profile based on time (Eg. day, week, year)

2) PayPal will bill customer's account automatically

Authorize.Net also has same feature called CIM (Customer Information Manager). It is more easier to store/access user profiles and payment profiles. Besides, you do not need to charge customer's credit card first.